# wget starting from arbitrary byte

Tags: wget

Using the `-c` flag, I can tell `wget` to resume a download. `wget` will then query the size of the pre-existing file to tell the server from where to resume the download.

Is there a way to tell `wget` to start from an arbitrary offset, i.e. an equivalent to `curl`'s `-C` option?

I know that I can always manually create a file with the right size, append the new data to it, and then remove the prefix, but it is very cumbersome to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from version 1.16, `--start-pos`. From the man page:

> ```
>    --start-pos=OFFSET
>       Start downloading at zero-based position OFFSET.  
>       Offset may be expressed in bytes, kilobytes with the `k' suffix,
>       or megabytes with the `m' suffix, etc.
>
>       --start-pos has higher precedence over --continue.  When
>       --start-pos and --continue are both specified, wget will emit a
>       warning then proceed as if --continue was absent.
>
>       Server support for continued download is required, otherwise
>       --start-pos cannot help.  See -c for details.
> ```

This option is unavailable for wget versions older than 1.16.

Comment: Which version of `wget` do you have? Mine is GNU wget 1.15 and this option is not mentioned in the man page neither recognized when I try it.

Comment: I can't tell you now, I'm no longer at the computer, but it's Debian Jessie's version.

Comment: From the [wget Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) page, this has been added in version 1.16. Updated your answer to precise it.

Comment: Indeed, Debian Jessie's wget is 1.16. My apologies for not mentioning the version previously, and thank you for the edit!